# Error on ConfigurationManager when attempting to insert data

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

So I'm trying to add data to a MySQL Server database.

Here is the code:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim conn As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Data Source=JOAOCOQUIM\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Teste;Integrated Security=True").ConnectionString
        Dim connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(conn)
        Dim sql As String = "Insert into [User] ([nome], [idade]) values (@nome, @idade)"
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", TextBox1.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idade", TextBox2.Text)


        connection.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        connection.Close()
    End Sub
End Class`
```

When I insert the data and click on the `Button` it show's me the following error:

[image: Image of the error]

Comment: Don't think you're using `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` correctly. Instead pass the connection string directly `SqlConnection("Data Source=JOAOCOQUIM\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Teste;Integrated Security=True")`

Comment: Please do not post links to pictures of errors.  Put the actual error message in the post - make it easy for others to help you.  Please read [Ask] and take the [Tour].

Answer (score 0):

So I did what Bugs said and it worked.

Here's the working code:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=JOAOCOQUIM\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Teste;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=JOAOCOQUIM\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Teste;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim sql As String = "Insert into [User] ([nome], [idade]) values (@nome, @idade)"
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", TextBox1.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idade", TextBox2.Text)


        connection.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        connection.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Not a problem, glad you got it working. You don't need `Dim conn As SqlConnection` however since you have `Dim connection As SqlConnection` and are using that connection.